# Arrays with Curiously Recurring Template Pattern?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-2008, crtp

I have a CRTP-based wrapper for a Windows `HANDLE`:

```
#include <windows.h>

template<class T>
class HandleT
{
    HANDLE handle;

    operator HANDLE() const { return this->handle; }

    static ULONG WaitForMultipleObjects(DWORD count, /* ??? */ objects[])
    {
        return WaitForMultipleObjects(count, ...);
    }
};

class EventHandle : Handle<EventHandle>
{
    //...
};

class FileHandle : Handle<FileHandle>
{
    //...
};
```

The trouble I'm having is, I have no idea what to substitute for `???` above. I can't say `HandleT<T>`, because they can be different kinds of handles, which wouldn't fit into an array. And I don't want to say `HANDLE`, because then the function wouldn't be working on `HandleT` objects at all -- the user might as well just avoid calling the wrapper entirely. And I can't use variadic templates, because I'm still in the pre-C++0x world.

Is there a known solution to this problem, or do I just have to use a non-ideal solution mentioned above?

Comment: Where is T used in the class?

Comment: @JohnPS: It's used in the part of the code that handles the management of the handle (i.e. closing it, etc.)... I didn't copy that part since it didn't seem too relevant.

Comment: Does the `object[]` array hold mixed types? If yes, then it seems like you would need regular polymorphism rather than CRTP. If each call to  `WaitForMultipleObjects` gets an array of the same type, then you could make that a template function.

Comment: @JohnPS: Yeah, the entire problem is the mixed types. I guess I could do regular polymorphism too, but CRTP is a *lot* handier for `DuplicateHandle`'s return type, because it can then return the same object type statically. Doing so with regular polymorphism would require lots of overriding and such.

Answer (score 0):

You may mix CRTP and polymorphism. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13868014/1902095

The idea is to have an interface class, `BaseHandle`, which would be used as polymorphic pointer within the array in question. `HandleT<>` would inherit the above class and implement common methods (and those methods that differ by T).