# CRTP and dynamic polymorphism compile error

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, standards, crtp

```
class A {
    virtual A* foo() = 0;
};

template<class T>
class B : public A {
    virtual T* foo() { return nullptr; }
};

class C : public B<C> {

};
```

This is a simplified implementation for [Possibility to mix composite pattern and curiously recurring template pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867901/possibility-to-mix-composite-pattern-and-curiously-recurring-template-pattern). I get the following error:

```
Return type of virtual function 'foo' is not covariant with the return type of the function it overrides ('C *' is not derived from 'A *')
```

Tested on clang 3.0, gcc 4.7 and visual studio 2008.

First solution:

```
class C : public A, public B<C> {}
```

compiles under visual studio with a warning that B is already a child of A and does **not** compile under clang with initial error.

Another workaround:

```
class D : public A {}
class C : public B<D> {}
```

solves the incompleteness issue, but I can't figure out how many A instances will I have. Intuition tells me that A is virtual, thus there should be only one.

Also this workaround creates unreadable code.

What does the standard states about this situation? Should this code compile? If not, why?

Comment: It's always good to keep in mind that `C` is incomplete in its list of bases.

Answer (score 4):

Your virtual function `A::foo()` returns an `A*`, while function `B<C>::foo()`, which is meant to override it, returns a `C*`.

This in theory does respect the principle of covariance, since `C` is indeed a specialization of (derives from) `A`, but at the point of instantiation, this is not known, because `C` is an incomplete type.

One possible way to re-think your design is to make `A` a class template as well, and let `B` propagate the template argument for `T` up to `A`:

```
template<typename T>
class A {
    virtual T* foo() = 0;
};

template<class T>
class B : public A<T> {
    virtual T* foo() { return nullptr; }
};
```

Concerning your workaround:

> What does the standard states about this situation? Should this code compile? If not, why?

It shouldn't compile, because the mere fact of making `C` also derive from `A` explicitly (notice, that you would end up with *two* distinct base sub-objects of type `A` inside `C`) does not make `C` a complete type when instantiating `B<C>`. Per Paragraph 9.2/2 of the C++11 Standard:

> **A class is considered a completely-defined object type (3.9) (or complete type) at the closing `}` of the *class-specifier*.**
>   Within the class *member-specification*, the class is regarded as complete within function bodies,
>   default arguments, and *brace-or-equal-initializers* for non-static data members (including such things in
>   nested classes). Otherwise it is regarded as incomplete within its own class *member-specification*.

Comment: Unfortunately this breaks the sole purpose of this code: to create polymorphic base class A.

Comment: *function B<C>::foo(), which is meant to override it, returns a B<C>** – am I reading it wrong, or does `B<C>::foo()` return `C*` instead?

Comment: @ulidtko: Correct, that was a mistake of mine. Thank you.

Comment: Also, what I'd like to see in the answer is **why** `C` isn't a complete type. (It looks to be completely defined, so uhh... what the hell.)

Comment: @ulidtko: That is because of the paragraph from the standard I quoted. A class type is complete only after the closing `}`. Here, `B<C>` is instantiated before the closing `}` is met. Therefore, `C` is incomplete and the compiler has the right not to know that it derives from `A`. This is the reason for the error saying covariance is not respected.

Comment: Ohh, now I can see. Interesting.

Comment: I second the concern raised by @VytisValentinavičius; now you cannot use derived objects through an A pointer without specifying the concrete type as the template parameter. Is there no other workaround for this?

Comment: Actually You may use `decltype(this)` to achieve similar result:
```class D : public A { virtual auto foo() -> decltype(this) { return this; } }```