# CRTP copy method warns of potential memory leak

Tags: c++, c++14, crtp, clang-static-analyzer

I have an object hierarchy and need to be able to clone objects from the base class. I've followed the typical CRTP pattern, except that I also want to be able to return the child class if copy is called on a child directly. To do that, I've followed the suggestion here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30252692/1180785

It seems to work fine, but Clang warns me that I have a potential memory leak. I've reduced the code down to this MCVE:

```c++
template <typename T>
class CRTP {
protected:
    virtual CRTP<T> *internal_copy(void) const {
        return new T(static_cast<const T&>(*this));
    }

public:
    T *copy(void) const {
        return static_cast<T*>(internal_copy());
    }

    virtual ~CRTP(void) = default;
};

class Impl : public CRTP<Impl> {
};

int main(void) {
    Impl a;
    Impl *b = a.copy();
    delete b;
}
```

As far as I can tell, there's no possible memory leak there, but running Clang through XCode shows this:

[image: Clang potential memory leak]

*Is* there a memory leak here? If not, what's causing the false positive and how can I work around it? (I'd rather not turn off static analysis)

Comment: The program you show [doesn't call `CRTP::copy`](http://rextester.com/UBB92957) at all. I suspect the code you run may be different from one you show.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik good point; I missed that while I was reducing it. However, the warning I posted is taken directly from the code I posted, so somehow it is indeed running CRTP::copy. That makes me think this could actually be a bug in the analyser related to virtual methods.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I have updated the code with an improved demonstration of the issue, which removes the unnecessary "virtual" on the copy and removes the array. This one does indeed call the CRTP::copy method, and the clang analysis is the same.

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't see a memory leak. Not sure why the analyzer complains. Maybe it doesn't like any function returning a raw pointer to allocated memory; or maybe the template dance confuses it enough that it can't prove that the caller does free the memory. Consider returning `std::unique_ptr<T>` in place of raw pointer.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik even using `unique_ptr` (`std::unique_ptr<T> copy(void) const { return std::unique_ptr<T>(static_cast<T*>(internal_copy())); }`) produces the warning. Interestingly, I've found that it disappears if I reverse the way copy & internal_copy are linked (i.e. if all logic is in copy, with no call to internal_copy, it's fine)

Comment: Why does internal_copy need to return `CRTP<T>*` instead of just `T*`?  Also, since `T` is the base of `CRTP<T>`, why does copy need to `static_cast` it?  I wonder if the analyzer is thinking that you're somehow losing information with all the changing of the pointer type.  Just a wild guess...

Comment: @cyberbisson see the linked answer for the full context of why it needs to be that way. It's basically because it can't override an existing method to return a type which it doesn't yet know is a sub-class of the original (the base class has been removed from my reduced example here). Also `T` is not the base of `CRTP<T>`; `CRTP<T>` is the base of `T` (which is what makes it curiously recursive!)

Comment: @Dave Oh duh, of course.  I skimmed the link, but didn't fully grok the covariance issue only presenting itself when it was overridden.  Ignore ignore ignore. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround which makes the analyser happy while still allowing the use of this pattern. Simply reverse the link between `copy` and `internal_copy`:

```
template <typename T>
class CRTP : public Base {
protected:
    virtual CRTP<T> *internal_copy(void) const {
        return copy();
    }

public:
    T *copy(void) const {
        return new T(static_cast<const T&>(*this));
    }
};
```

This still works in the context of the original suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30252692/1180785), because when resolving `copy` inside CRTP, it will prefer CRTP's override (even though it isn't a virtual method), so there is no infinite loop.

As for why the analyser is happy with this order but unhappy with the original order, I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

I think the analyzer is getting confused by the `static_cast` in your `copy` method.  If you simply change it to `dynamic_cast`, it ceases to flag the line as a memory leak.  This leads me to believe that it thinks you are possibly casting a base type instance (`CRTP<T>`) to its derived type (`T`), which would of course be invalid when dereferenced.  You are obviously not doing this, so this may be a bug in the leak detector, or it may be onto something more subtle than what I'm thinking about right now.  It may not be an error now, but if `Impl` becomes a more complicated type (e.g., one with multiple inheritance), it may become an issue (as will your `static_cast` in the copy-CTOR invocation).

This implementation (with fewer casts) had zero leaks for me as well:

```
template <typename T>
class CRTP {
protected:
    virtual T *internal_copy() const {
        return new T(static_cast<const T&>(*this));
    }

public:
    T *copy() const {
        return internal_copy();
    }

    virtual ~CRTP() = default;
};
```

Comment: See my answer to your comment for an explanation of why `internal_copy` can't return `T*` in this use-case. Interesting that `dynamic_cast` makes it happy; it isn't something I tested because I'm using `-no-rtti`, but as you say; perhaps it just thinks the static_cast might cast to the wrong type.