# C++ abstract base template for forwarding with covariant return

Tags: c++, crtp

I'm trying to use CRTP and covariance to implement forwarding:

```
class Display {  // interface
    virtual Display& drawCircle(...) = 0;
    virtual Display& drawRect(...) = 0;
    // etc. lots of these.
};
class ADisplay<R> : public Display {
     virtual Display& getWrapped();
     virtual R& drawCircle(...) { getWrapped().drawCircle(...); return *this; }
     virtual R& drawRect(...) { getWrapped().drawRect(...); return *this; }
     // etc?
};
class B : public ADisplay<B> {
     Display& wrapped;
     virtual Display& getWrapped() { return wrapped; }
     B& methodSpecificToB() {...}
};
```

This would be used in a "builder" style:

```
B b;
b.drawCircle(1,2,3)
 .drawRect(4,5,6)
 .methodSpecificToB();
```

This, perhaps unsurprisingly, doesn't work because ADisplay<B> is [not completely defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570333/crtp-and-dynamic-polymorphism-compile-error) at the point of instantiation.

Can you think of some other way to do this?

Comment: Would making a new class `C`, which defines all methods in `B`, but doesn't derive from `ADisplay` work? Then have `B` derive from `ADisplay<C>`?

Comment: @user1520427 I don't believe adding another level of indirection would help to improve this design.

Comment: BTW: I prefer using CRTP's to eliminate virtual calls at all. I can always do a safe `static_cast` to the deriving class, and provide 'Implementation hooks' for the deriving class (doing NOP's in the base implementation). Sometimes I'm stretching them to use 'handmade' vtables using static function pointers with an argument that can again be safely statically casted to the deriving class.

Comment: What about reversing the inheritance: Let `ADisplay<B>` derive from `B`, and `B` directly from `Display`.

Comment: Another point: The builder pattern you want to use here, usually applies better to do configuration of particular classes, than calling behavior (actions like drawing) on them. Not I want to claim it's not possible.

Comment: @DyP And what's the role (point of) `ADisplay<B>` then? (mixins are better done via template parameters, aren't they?)

Comment: @g-makulik It's not entirely clear to me what the role of `ADisplay` is in the OP. If it's to simplify redirecting the virtual functions of `Display` to another object (here: `wrapped`), then this can as well be achieved by "reversing" the CRTP.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a hint (I don't want to elaborate fully now, it's late on my side of the bowl), you can always do (**note** without having an abstract `Display` interface):

```
template<class R>
class ADisplay<R> 
{
public:
    R& drawCircle(...) 
    { 
        static_cast<R*>(this)->drawCircleImpl(...); 
        return *static_cast<R*>(this); 
    }
    R& drawRect(...) 
    { 
        static_cast<R*>(this)->drawRectImpl(...); 
        return *static_cast<R*>(this); 
    }
protected:
    R& drawCircleImpl(...)
    {
        // May be have some static assert here, if you want to have this method
        // 'abstract'. Otherwise provide some reasonable base implementation, or
        // delegate to a mixin (provided as another template parameter)
    }

    R& drawRectImpl(...)
    {  
        // Same as above ...
    }
};
```

What's the purpose of an abstract interface, where the client has to know about the specific implementation methods anyway?

Answer (score 0):

These functions:

```
virtual R& drawCircle(...) { getWrapped()->drawCircle(...); return *this; }
virtual R& drawRect(...) { getWrapped()->drawRect(...); return *this; }
```

should be:

```
virtual ADisplay<R>& drawCircle(...) { getWrapped()->drawCircle(...); return *this; }
virtual ADisplay<R>& drawRect(...) { getWrapped()->drawRect(...); return *this; }
```

Comment: @ChristopherMason Isn't it possible to change the order of the `B` specific calls to appear first (and return a reference to `B` of course)?

Comment: @g-makulik Perhaps, but I think it's likely to be surprising to users.  If I can't solve this more elegantly, I'd probably just repeat the forwarding in every implementation...

Comment: @ChristopherMason Yeah, may be a bit surprising. But as long the **behavior is clearly documented** that all specific methods (only the client will know anyways) should be called first, and then you can proceed with the more common stuff, it would be OK for me.